# Potential such that the time-independent Schroedinger equation has an explicit solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

Consider the time-independent Schroedinger equation

$\phi'' (x) +V(x)\phi(x)=\lambda \phi(x)$, $\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$.

For testing my numerics, I would like to now:

**For which choices of $V$ are there explicit expressions for the solutions $(\phi,\lambda)$?**

For example, if $V(x)=x^2$, then the solutions are products of Hermite polynomials and $exp(-x^2)$ (up to correct scales) and arithmetic progressions (the same works in higher dimensions with the analogue potential).

Comment: for which $V$ do we know how to diagonalize $\nabla^2 + V$ ? there are the one particule problems which should correspond to a radial $1/r^2$ and $1/r$ potential I think.

Comment: and see [wiki/List of quantum-mechanical systems with analytical solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum-mechanical_systems_with_analytical_solutions)

Answer (score 0):

You can always work backwards if you just want a single solution: start with known physically plausible choices of any $\phi(x)$ and $\lambda$, then insert these into the Schrodinger equation to determine the $V(x)$. (Caveat. This is a math hack for getting a single explicit solution that can be tested numerically, not a physically reasonable approach  to finding ALL solutions.)